# Composing image in c#

Tags: .net, image, bitmap

I have a large image in photoshop, with many layers. I have all the layers in Bitmap format. For each step of a visualization process I hide and show some layers, I move some, I rotate some, and I edit some texts. All based on data I currently have in excel (but it could be in a database or whatever).
What I want, is to automate this based on rules I can program. My question is: **how can I best draw an image based on bitmap resources then save it to a jpg from C#?**

I feel GDI+ is a bit low-level for this, but if no other free solution presents itself, I'll have to try that...

Comment: GDI is like using Paint. It can be done, but I'd rather use Photoshop if possible. Am I thinking wrong?

Comment: So...you want C# code that manipulates the layers in Photoshop directly? From your description this sounds exactly like a GDI+ task. It wouldn't be too hard either since all the operations you describe are well defined in C# using matrices.

Comment: @Pedery: Okay, then obviously my knowledge of GDI+ is limited at the basic stuff. I figured GDI is for drawing primitives and stuff

Comment: I'll add a proper answer to your question, so we can continue that thread there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, GDI and GDI+ are two very different things. You probably want to work with GDI+. I have myself made several photo-manipulation programs in GDI+, so you have all the tools you need right there.

What you want to do is to get hold of the Graphics object of each bitmap. Using this you can use the object's transformation matrix or rotation matrix to achieve the effects you want. The DrawString method should accomplish your text needs.

If you need to blend images (using blending modes), you can use the Lockbits method and iterate over the the pixels manually. It's pretty straightforward.

This should give you all the pointers you need to solve the problem at hand.

Comment: I've read stuff about GDI+, it says for Win7 and forward it's planned to be superceeded by Direct2D. Is that something I should be familiar with?

Comment: GDI+ is probably your fastest way to a solution here. It's easy to use and there are tonnes of examples out there. I more or less outlined your entire solution in my answer. Regardless of what framework you want to use, you're likely to use the same matrices in order to reach your goal. Not sure whether Direct2D will be out-of-the-box compatible with XP either.